# How to disable macOS catching CTRL-A when running screen

Tags: macos

I am connecting to a Linux computer through the serial port using *screen* on my Mac.

I ran *minicom* on my Linux computer and minicom uses CTRL-A for commands.

But if I enter CTRL-A, the macOS catches this and tries to interpret the command.  Is there a way to temporarily disable the macOS from interpreting the CTRL-A?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> is used by `screen` to initiate a command sequence. You can either press <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>  to send CTRL-A to the other computer or redefine it with the `-e` option (see `man screen` for details).

Comment: I did not have time earlier to try your suggestion.  Just testing this today.  CTRL-A a does not work for me.  It did not pass to minicom.  And for the screen -e command, looks like I have to do this for each command, is this correct?  Or can I change all CTRL-A commands to say CTRL-B commands?

Comment: You can change the prefix with the -e option, see the man page for details